# generating a list of strings based off variables

Tags: terraform

lets say I have some terraform vars: `variable "cluster" {}` and `variable "kfkcount" {}`

and lets say `cluster=test` and `kfkcount=3`

how can I use terraform to turn that into a list that looks like this?

`["test1.c.com",  "test2.c.com", "test3.c.com"]`

Answer (score 9):

This should do what you want:

```
variable "cluster" {}

variable "kfkcount" {}

data "template_file" "test" {
  template = "$${cluster}$${index}.c.com"
  count    = "${var.kfkcount}"

  vars = {
    index   = "${count.index + 1}"
    cluster = "${var.cluster}"
  }
}

output "list" {
  value = "${data.template_file.test.*.rendered}"
}
```

It's a bit of a hack using the `template_file` resource, however it will return the list as required:

```
$ terraform apply
var.cluster
  Enter a value: test

var.kfkcount
  Enter a value: 3

data.template_file.test[0]: Refreshing state...
data.template_file.test[1]: Refreshing state...
data.template_file.test[2]: Refreshing state...

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

list = [
    test1.c.com,
    test2.c.com,
    test3.c.com
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Quite late to the party but if you end up here like me. This can be solved with the `range` function.

```
formatlist("${var.cluster}%s.c.com", range(1, var.kfkcount + 1))
```

will output:

```
tolist(["test1.c.com", "test2.c.com", "test3.c.com",])
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

One thing that can help is to use [count](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#count) for looping, and using the `count.index` as the value for the names.
So you could end up with something like this:

```
resource ".." "..." {
  count = "${var.kfkcount}"

  something = "${var.cluster}${count.index}.c.com"
}
```

There is even [one example](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/tree/master/examples/count) that shows a simple usage of count and, also, list expansion with `*`.

---

Have you tried using `list(items, ...)` described in the [Interpolation Syntax](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#list-items-) page?

Something in the like of

`"${list("${var.cluster}", "${var.kfkcount}")}"`

Comment: That will return `["test", 3]` and may error because the list contains different types. I can't think of a good way to repeat a string in Terraform though because you can't do something like `"${var.cluster * var.kfkcount}"` to repeat the string 3 times before turning it into a list. Not sure this is actually doable.

Comment: @user2061886 , now I edited the answer with, looks like, is more aligned with what you need.